# How to access super class's method's local variable in Python

Tags: python

Potentially a stupid question but will ask anyway :D

I have a class which has the following method:

```py
class asyncClassA():
    async def geta(self):
        a = "hello"
        b = "world"
        return a
```

A second class inherits the first class and overrides the method:

```py
class asyncClassB(asyncClassA):
    async def geta(self):
        a = await super(asyncClassB, self).geta()
        b = ??
```

Now how can I access var `b` from the `asyncClassA.geta()`? Do I have to re-write the whole method to get the `b`? or is there any other pythonic way to get it and use it in `asyncClassB.geta()`?

Comment: Drop the `var` keyword(?) to make this valid Python.

Comment: And yes, you should rewrite the code. Local variables are inaccessible outside the function by design.

Comment: local variables (by definition) cannot be accessed outside the functions that define them.

Comment: Or just return both values: `return a, b`.

Comment: @chepner I can't return both because they are set in the package and i dont want to change `package classes`

Comment: @rdas yup that's why I said its stupid question coz already knew it can't be accessed :D but thought if i could avoid copying parent class's method